# 'Normalization' of free particle wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I'm trying to obtain the expression for the free particle that is known $$\psi_p(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{i\frac{xp}{\hbar}}$$

Easily you can arrive to the exponential,

$$p\langle x|p\rangle=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x|p\rangle \quad \Rightarrow \quad \langle x|p\rangle=\psi_p(x)\propto e^{i\frac{xp}{\hbar}}$$

Now we have to find the 'normalisation' $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$, its obvious that this function is not square integrable, i.e. the integral all over the space is infinite, but I know that as a convention we integrate over a certain space, if we try to obtain the normalisation constant,

$$\langle x|x'\rangle=\delta(x-x')$$
$$\langle x|x'\rangle=\int \langle x|p\rangle\langle p|x'\rangle dp=|N|^2 \int \psi_p(x)\psi_p^*(x')dp=|N|^2\int \exp\left(ip\frac{x-x'}{\hbar}\right)dp$$

$$\langle x|x'\rangle=|N|^2 \frac{\hbar}{i(x-x')}\left.\exp\left(ip\frac{x-x'}{\hbar}\right)\right|_{p_0}^{p_1}$$

I dont' know if there is other way to go to this integral, but in this case, that we are integrating the momentum, if we can do it like this, what are the integration limits and what significate we can give to it, why we choose this ones an not others? In the case that the problem is solved like this.

Comment: The right-hand-side of your first formula is the fundamental definition of $\langle x|p\rangle$ that yields consistent normalizations for *p* and *x*, δ-functions, etc. Your voice of the infinite normalization of a plane wave is arbitrary, and connects configuration and momentum space wave-functions... Sakurai and Napolitano explain this to you.

Comment: ... voice --> choice...